# unterminated string constant Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I know what "Unterminated String Constant" signifies. I have gone through all the relevant questions as well but could not find any solution in my case.

I use jQuery 1.7 extensively on my web page. I have many javascript functions as well. I have installed my files in many different environments but never got this error. After debugging my javascript functions in IE Developer Tool, I see that the code does not break in any of my javsacript function. But when everything gets over, jQuery1.7.js is called and after executing all the internal functional calls I get this error.

I have tried and monitored the jquery variables as well but cannot pin point any particular place where the code might break with such error. Does anyone have any idea where should I check my code? I think that when I make an ajax call, the error appears at the end, after the call is finished and after the success function is completed. But, I don't know why.

I don't know any better words to convey my problem, let me know if you need any more info.

thanksc

Comment: So you know the error is in jQuery1.7.js - which line? Have you tried using an unminified version and inspecting the line? Is it a problem in Chrome, Safari, etc?

Comment: It sounds like the ajax data may contain a " character which makes jQuery think there is unterminated data.

Comment: Does the error happen in another browser like Chrome or Firefox? Use their tools. If not, start commenting out chunks of code until it goes away.

Comment: @adam: I know in wat part of my data I get an error. I have tried monitoring jQuery variables storing that data. Will try unminified version as well.

Comment: @SandorA: I have a JSON data in ajax response that goes to jQuery variables. there are no " or ' in the ajax response itself.

Comment: @epascarello: will try that as well!

Comment: @Rishabh it may also be cause by a newline character or if your ajax call is returning data from a text file it you might want to check to make sure the file is encoded as UTF-8 and not ANSI.